# THREE.js Limit Zooming in mousewheel event

Tags: javascript, three.js, mousewheel, orbit, trackball

Can anyone please tell me how to limit zooming in and out of an model in three.js. I came across trackball controls but there is no function or property to limit zooming.Tried using orbit controls also but when using along with trackball controls i could find some issues in rotation and panning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both `TrackballControls` and `OrbitControls` have `.minDistance` and `.maxDistance` properties.

Comment: Trackball controls .minDistance and .maxDistance differs from orbit controls's property

Comment: In trackball control it fails to limit zooming as it does in orbit controls.If you could do so,please provide me with a js fiddle.

Comment: Nice demanding )) Could you show what you've done already or provide a js fiddle? For me, `.minDistance` and `.maxDistance` work as good as they meant to be. In both kinds of controls.

Comment: controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
                controls.minZoom = 10;
                controls.maxZoom = 100; I used this in orbit control,it works fine but it didnt work for trackball controls in same case.it is initially setting the near and far value while loading

Comment: Now it's more clear. TrackballControls don't have `.minZoom` and `.maxZoom` properties.

Comment: In three version 70 they have only .minDistance and .maxDistance.In recent version FYI .minDistance and .maxDistance is for perspective camera and .minZoom and .maxZoom is for orthographic camera to limit zooming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132761/discussion-between-prisoner849-and-aasha-joney).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working with THREE.js version70 which doesn't support to limit zooming. In current THREE.js version 83 of Trackball controls we could limit the zooming in and out using the following code,

```
controls.minDistance = 10;
controls.maxDistance = 100;
```